# How to resolve Procedure with date is incompatible with int

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

I have this procedure that just started out of the blue giving me the error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure TimeBilling_Import_New, Line 23
> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Unsure why it started giving me this error after working for weeks before with no issue but i went and tried to update it with `DATEADD(day, 0, GETDATE())` as that should have worked but am still getting the error.

```
USE [CTDD]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:
-- Create date: 1-28-2021
-- Description: TimeBilling Merge Stored Proc
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TimeBilling_Import_New] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE INTO [CTDD].[DBO].[TimeBilling_Raw_New] AS TARGET 
    USING OPENQUERY ([XXX.XXXX.COM], 'SELECT * FROM insights.timebilling WHERE RowModifiedAt > DATEADD(day, 0, GetDate())') AS SOURCE 

    -- Update Operation -- 

    -- Comparison Operation

    ON (TARGET.TimeBillingId = SOURCE.TimeBillingId) 

    WHEN MATCHED 
        AND TARGET.TimeBillingClientId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingClientId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingInsuranceId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingInsuranceId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingPayorPlanId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingPayorPlanId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingProviderId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceCodeId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceCodeId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceFacilityId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceFacilityId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingBillingCreatedOn <> SOURCE.TimeBillingBillingCreatedOn
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingEntryDate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingEntryDate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceDate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceDate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingVoidDate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingVoidDate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingDeletedDate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingDeletedDate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingCreationTime <> SOURCE.TimeBillingCreationTime
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingVoidTime <> SOURCE.TimeBillingVoidTime
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceUnits <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceUnits
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingDriveTime <> SOURCE.TimeBillingDriveTime
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingMilesDriven <> SOURCE.TimeBillingMilesDriven
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingClientMileageRate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingClientMileageRate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingClientServiceRate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingClientServiceRate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingClientAgreedServiceRate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingClientAgreedServiceRate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingClientDriveRate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingClientDriveRate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingProviderMileageRate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderMileageRate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingProviderDriveRate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderDriveRate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingProviderServiceRate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderServiceRate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingPatientResponsibilityAmount <> SOURCE.TimeBillingPatientResponsibilityAmount
        OR TARGET.ClientChargesTotal <> SOURCE.ClientChargesTotal
        OR TARGET.ClientChargesAgreedTotal <> SOURCE.ClientChargesAgreedTotal
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingFirstBilledDate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingFirstBilledDate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingAuthorizationId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingAuthorizationId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifierCode1 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode1
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifierCode2 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode2
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifierCode3 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode3
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifierCode4 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode4
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifierDescription1 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription1
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifierDescription2 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription2
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifierDescription3 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription3
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifierDescription4 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription4
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingCreateDate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingCreateDate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifyDate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifyDate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceLocationName <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceLocationName
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceAddress1 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceAddress1
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceAddress2 <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceAddress2
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceCity <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceCity
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceStateProvince <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceStateProvince
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServicePostalCode <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServicePostalCode
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingServiceCounty <> SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceCounty
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingCreatedByContactId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingCreatedByContactId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingModifiedByContactId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingModifiedByContactId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingLastBilledDate <> SOURCE.TimeBillingLastBilledDate
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingGroupId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingGroupId
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingProviderSignature <> SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderSignature
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingClientSignature <> SOURCE.TimeBillingClientSignature
        OR TARGET.TimeBillingOrganizationId <> SOURCE.TimeBillingOrganizationId

    -- Update Target records --
    THEN UPDATE
        SET TARGET.TimeBillingClientId = SOURCE.TimeBillingClientId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingInsuranceId =  SOURCE.TimeBillingInsuranceId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingPayorPlanId = SOURCE.TimeBillingPayorPlanId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingProviderId = SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceCodeId = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceCodeId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceFacilityId = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceFacilityId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingBillingCreatedOn = SOURCE.TimeBillingBillingCreatedOn,
            TARGET.TimeBillingEntryDate = SOURCE.TimeBillingEntryDate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceDate = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceDate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingVoidDate = SOURCE.TimeBillingVoidDate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingDeletedDate = SOURCE.TimeBillingDeletedDate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingCreationTime = SOURCE.TimeBillingCreationTime,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceStartTime = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceStartTime,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceEndTime = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceEndTime,
            TARGET.TimeBillingVoidTime = SOURCE.TimeBillingVoidTime,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceUnits = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceUnits,
            TARGET.TimeBillingDriveTime = SOURCE.TimeBillingDriveTime,
            TARGET.TimeBillingMilesDriven = SOURCE.TimeBillingMilesDriven,
            TARGET.TimeBillingClientMileageRate = SOURCE.TimeBillingClientMileageRate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingClientServiceRate = SOURCE.TimeBillingClientServiceRate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingClientAgreedServiceRate = SOURCE.TimeBillingClientAgreedServiceRate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingClientDriveRate = SOURCE.TimeBillingClientDriveRate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingProviderMileageRate = SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderMileageRate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingProviderDriveRate = SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderDriveRate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingProviderServiceRate = SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderServiceRate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingPatientResponsibilityAmount = SOURCE.TimeBillingPatientResponsibilityAmount,
            TARGET.ClientChargesTotal = SOURCE.ClientChargesTotal,
            TARGET.ClientChargesAgreedTotal = SOURCE.ClientChargesAgreedTotal,
            TARGET.TimeBillingFirstBilledDate = SOURCE.TimeBillingFirstBilledDate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingAuthorizationId = SOURCE.TimeBillingAuthorizationId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifierCode1 = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode1,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifierCode2 = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode2,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifierCode3 = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode3,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifierCode4 = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode4,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifierDescription1 = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription1,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifierDescription2 = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription2,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifierDescription3 = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription3,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifierDescription4 = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription4,
            TARGET.TimeBillingCreateDate = SOURCE.TimeBillingCreateDate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifyDate = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifyDate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceLocationName = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceLocationName,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceAddress1 = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceAddress1,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceAddress2 = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceAddress2,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceCity = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceCity,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceStateProvince = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceStateProvince,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServicePostalCode = SOURCE.TimeBillingServicePostalCode,
            TARGET.TimeBillingServiceCounty = SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceCounty,
            TARGET.TimeBillingCreatedByContactId = SOURCE.TimeBillingCreatedByContactId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingModifiedByContactId = SOURCE.TimeBillingModifiedByContactId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingLastBilledDate = SOURCE.TimeBillingLastBilledDate,
            TARGET.TimeBillingGroupId = SOURCE.TimeBillingGroupId,
            TARGET.TimeBillingProviderSignature = SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderSignature,
            TARGET.TimeBillingClientSignature = SOURCE.TimeBillingClientSignature,
            TARGET.TimeBillingOrganizationId = SOURCE.TimeBillingOrganizationId

    -- Insert Operation --

    -- Insert Unmatched Records into Target -- 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (TimeBillingClientId,
        TimeBillingInsuranceId,
        TimeBillingPayorPlanId,
        TimeBillingProviderId,
        TimeBillingServiceCodeId,
        TimeBillingServiceFacilityId,
        TimeBillingBillingCreatedOn,
        TimeBillingEntryDate,
        TimeBillingServiceDate,
        TimeBillingVoidDate,
        TimeBillingDeletedDate,
        TimeBillingCreationTime,
        TimeBillingServiceStartTime,
        TimeBillingServiceEndTime,
        TimeBillingVoidTime,
        TimeBillingId,
        TimeBillingServiceUnits,
        TimeBillingDriveTime,
        TimeBillingMilesDriven,
        TimeBillingClientMileageRate,
        TimeBillingClientServiceRate,
        TimeBillingClientAgreedServiceRate,
        TimeBillingClientDriveRate,
        TimeBillingProviderMileageRate,
        TimeBillingProviderDriveRate,
        TimeBillingProviderServiceRate,
        TimeBillingPatientResponsibilityAmount,
        ClientChargesTotal,
        ClientChargesAgreedTotal,
        TimeBillingFirstBilledDate,
        TimeBillingAuthorizationId,
        TimeBillingModifierCode1,
        TimeBillingModifierCode2,
        TimeBillingModifierCode3,
        TimeBillingModifierCode4,
        TimeBillingModifierDescription1,
        TimeBillingModifierDescription2,
        TimeBillingModifierDescription3,
        TimeBillingModifierDescription4,
        TimeBillingCreateDate,
        TimeBillingModifyDate,
        TimeBillingServiceLocationName,
        TimeBillingServiceAddress1,
        TimeBillingServiceAddress2,
        TimeBillingServiceCity,
        TimeBillingServiceStateProvince,
        TimeBillingServicePostalCode,
        TimeBillingServiceCounty,
        TimeBillingCreatedByContactId,
        TimeBillingModifiedByContactId,
        TimeBillingLastBilledDate,
        TimeBillingGroupId,
        TimeBillingProviderSignature,
        TimeBillingClientSignature,
        TimeBillingOrganizationId)       
        VALUES (SOURCE.TimeBillingClientId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingInsuranceId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingPayorPlanId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceCodeId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceFacilityId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingBillingCreatedOn,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingEntryDate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceDate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingVoidDate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingDeletedDate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingCreationTime,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceStartTime,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceEndTime,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingVoidTime,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceUnits,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingDriveTime,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingMilesDriven,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingClientMileageRate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingClientServiceRate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingClientAgreedServiceRate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingClientDriveRate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderMileageRate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderDriveRate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderServiceRate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingPatientResponsibilityAmount,
        SOURCE.ClientChargesTotal,
        SOURCE.ClientChargesAgreedTotal,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingFirstBilledDate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingAuthorizationId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode1,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode2,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode3,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierCode4,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription1,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription2,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription3,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifierDescription4,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingCreateDate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifyDate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceLocationName,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceAddress1,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceAddress2,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceCity,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceStateProvince,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServicePostalCode,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingServiceCounty,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingCreatedByContactId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingModifiedByContactId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingLastBilledDate,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingGroupId,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingProviderSignature,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingClientSignature,
        SOURCE.TimeBillingOrganizationId) 

    -- Delete Operation --

    -- Delete Records in Target that do not exist in source --

;
-- end of merge operation --
END
```

Added a dateadd to see if that would correct the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the openquery call and not in the merge. And what's the datatype of RowModifiedAt

Comment: Maybe someone changed the data type of a column? We don't have the definition of your table(s), so we can't inspect the problems.

Comment: Side note, I *hope* that all your columns are non-`NULL`able, otherwise that query isn't going to work as you expect. I somehow *doubt* that they are all non-`NULL`able though (for example, what value would a row have for `SOURCE.TimeBillingDeletedDate` when the row isn't "deleted"?)

Comment: Something i did see is when i go to execute it is, this, would that return_value int cause an issue?

USE [CTDD]
GO

DECLARE @ return_value int

EXEC @ return_value = [dbo].[TimeBilling_Import_New]

SELECT 'Return Value' = @ return_value

GO

Comment: Side note: It appears that you are missing a set of grouping parentheses around your `OR` conditions. `WHEN MATCHED AND TGT.Col1 <> SRC.Col1 OR TGT.Col2 <> SRC.Col2 OR ...` should likely be `WHEN MATCHED AND (TGT.Col1 <> SRC.Col1 OR TGT.Col2 <> SRC.Col2 OR ...)`. You might also look into the new `IS DISTINCT FROM` operator that nicely handles nulls.  Also, what is the intent of `DATEADD(day, 0, GetDate())`? As far as I know, that will just return the original `GetDate()` value. If the intent is to truncate to date-only, that is not happening.

Comment: (Please ignore the DATEADD question in your previous comment - just saw that you added that intentionally.) I scanned your code and don't see anything obvious. The only things I can think of are (1) One of the source column types are not as expected. Perhaps one of the date columns was accidentally loaded as an integer-encoded date. (2) Check the data type of the RowModifiedAt in the source table for the same reason. My only other suggestion is to start commenting out chunks of code in the procedure (and run it in a `BEGIN TRANACTION ...ROLLBACK` block until the error goes away.

Comment: What is the point of `DATEADD(day, 0, GetDate())`? That is literally the exact same thing as getdate(). I suspect you probably want something like `convert(date, getdate())` instead.